# Is it safe to delete the auto-generated resource files in visual studio 2012?

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2012

Is it safe to delete the auto-generated resource files in visual studio 2012?
I have selected them in this image:

[image]

Thanks

Comment: Depends ... is is a UI application or a command line application ?

Comment: command line application

Comment: I suggest you "remove" (do not delete the files) them from the solution and more all the "#include" for the resource file and rebuild your solution; if it works it works, if it does not compile, then there is a dependency  to the resources somewhere (string ID, ... ); either fix the dependencies or insert back the 2 files in the project.